Issues with Saxon schema validation during transform
Edited per comments to not use images. Had not considered it being a negative for some users.
We are developing an application in which we create some XML files (S1000D data modules) that are extracted from a "composite" set of data. Once the files are extracted from the composite, we are validating them. We are running into an issue where the schema is being reported as invalid:
Loading schema document file:/C:/GitRepos/Flight-Publishing-GUI/schemas/S1000D_4-2/xml_schema_flat/crew.xsd
Loading schema document http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink
Finished loading schema document http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink
Loading schema document file:/C:/GitRepos/Flight-Publishing-GUI/schemas/S1000D_4-2/xml_schema_flat/rdf.xsd
Loading schema document file:/C:/GitRepos/Flight-Publishing-GUI/schemas/S1000D_4-2/xml_schema_flat/dc.xsd
Finished loading schema document file:/C:/GitRepos/Flight-Publishing-GUI/schemas/S1000D_4-2/xml_schema_flat/dc.xsd
Finished loading schema document file:/C:/GitRepos/Flight-Publishing-GUI/schemas/S1000D_4-2/xml_schema_flat/rdf.xsd
Finished loading schema document file:/C:/GitRepos/Flight-Publishing-GUI/schemas/S1000D_4-2/xml_schema_flat/crew.xsd
Error on line 948 of crew.xsd:
   Unknown type Q{http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink}XLINKATT
Error on line 3578 of crew.xsd:
   Unknown type Q{http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink}XLINKATT3
Error on line 3703 of crew.xsd:
   Unknown type Q{http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink}XLINKATT1
Error on line 1222 of crew.xsd:
   Unknown type Q{http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink}XLINKATT4
Error on line 1139 of crew.xsd:
   Unknown type Q{http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink}XLINKATT
Error on line 1185 of crew.xsd:
   Unknown type Q{http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink}XLINKATT
Error on line 5507 of crew.xsd:
   Unknown type Q{http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink}XLINKATT0
Error on line 5552 of crew.xsd:
   Unknown type Q{http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink}XLINKATT2
Error on line 5651 of crew.xsd:
   Unknown type Q{http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink}XLINKATT0
Warning 
   Errors were found in the schema
Warning 
   Validation will continue without the schema at
  http://www.s1000d.org/S1000D_4-2/xml_schema_flat/crew.xsd

Content of crew.xsd in the area of line 948 in crew.xsd:
<xs:complexType name="dmRefElemType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="dmRefIdent"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="dmRefAddressItems"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="behavior"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute ref="referredFragment"/>
    <xs:attribute ref="applicRefId"/>
    <xs:attribute ref="id"/>
    <xs:attributeGroup ref="changeAttGroup"/>
    <xs:attributeGroup ref="securityAttGroup"/>
    <xs:attributeGroup ref="authorityAttGroup"/>
    <xs:attributeGroup ref="xlink:XLINKATT"/>
</xs:complexType>

When I review the schema I can find all of the referenced 'Unknown type' items. Oxygen has no issues with it and validates files using it. We are using a catalog file to point to the local 'schema' folder where all the S1000D V4.2 schemas are being stored (to include the xlink.xsd). The catalog.xml looks like:
<!DOCTYPE catalog
 PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD Entity Resolution XML Catalog V1.0//EN"
 "http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/entity/release/1.0/catalog.dtd">
<catalog  xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog catalog.xsd"
          prefer="system">
  <rewriteSystem systemIdStartString="http://www.s1000d.org/" rewritePrefix="schemas/" />
  <rewriteURI uriStartString="http://www.s1000d.org/" rewritePrefix="schemas/" />
</catalog>

When running this XSL from Oxygen, these errors did not occur. It was not until building the Java application to use them that it appeared. We provide the catalog to Saxon like this:
Processor xsl_proc = new Processor(config);
xsl_proc.setCatalogFiles("catalog.xml");

Hoping that someone has any ideas as to how to get this resolved.

Always include text as copied characters, not as images.  We can’t paste an image into a text editor or IDE.  Sight impaired users will be unable to help you at all.  And images tend to be harder to read than characters rendered in a browser font.

What happens when you use Saxon from the command line to try a validation with that catalog file? Any errors/warnings? Try -t to get better diagnostics.

The error suggests the schema crew.xsd is read from the server, not locally. Can you post the error messages as text so that we can copy URIs and check schemas?

@MartinHonnen I switched the '-t' back on and posted that portion of the log with more details. It looks like it reads the schema from the catalog, but also see where it refers to the server based version. Looking into the XSL that is using saxon:validate to see if anything is off there.

Looking longer at that list of log messages, I see something kind of odd. It is loading the xlink schema from the web, but the other schemas are being loaded from the schema folder. Is it possible that is the issue?

I think Saxon has an internal copy of W3C schemas like the XLink one in its resolver data resources, to avoid making calls to the W3C HTTP server. But I can't really interpret that -t data to tell, let's hope Michael Kay comes along later and can tell based on it what might be wrong or what to change.

Got a solution. I think it may have been an oversight, or simply did not realize it was needed. I edited the catalog file to also handle the 'xlink' uri:
<!DOCTYPE catalog
 PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD Entity Resolution XML Catalog V1.0//EN"
 "http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/entity/release/1.0/catalog.dtd">
<catalog xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:tc:entity:xmlns:xml:catalog catalog.xsd"
          prefer="system">
  <rewriteSystem systemIdStartString="http://www.s1000d.org/" rewritePrefix="schemas/" />
  <rewriteURI uriStartString="http://www.s1000d.org/" rewritePrefix="schemas/" />
  <uri name="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" uri="schemas/S1000D_4-2/xml_schema_flat/xlink.xsd"/>
</catalog>

Everything ran through and validation was performed. Thanks to everyone who took time to look and provide feedback.

You'll find some background to this problem at https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/5652
The underlying issue is that various application-level standards (including it appears s1000d) have taken it upon themselves to issue variants of the W3C XLink schema, without changing the namespace. In theory a schema processor can ignore the "location hint" for schema documents if it recognizes the namespace URI of the schema as being one that it knows about. The problem is that Saxon thinks it knows what the Xlink schema is, and it thinks it's the W3C version, but not everyone agrees.
So as the comment thread for 5652 shows, we had to backtrack a bit and give applications the opportunity to load private non-standard versions of the XLink schema, and we had to do this where possible without breaking backwards compatibility. So the current situation is a little bit messy...

Thank you for the information, makes things much clearer as to the behavior I was getting.
